# What is the most optimal way to convert Array to Object Array including array entries as object keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Consider the following two arrays:

```
var array=[
["2021-06-11", 100, 80, 70],
["2021-06-12", 101, 81, 71],
["2021-06-13", 102, 82, 72],
["2021-06-14", 103, 83, 73]]

var keyNames = ["date","a","b","c"];
```

Target:

```
var newArray = [{date:"2021-06-11",a:100,b:80,c:70},
                {date:"2021-06-12",a:101,b:81,c:71},
                {date:"2021-06-13",a:102,b:82,c:72},
                {date:"2021-06-14",a:103,b:83,c:73}]
```

What is the most optimal way to achieve this? can be done with **forEach()** or a combination with **reduce** / **map** prototyping?

I've tried with `var obj = Object.assign({}, array)`
but the result was index as keys

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you for your time!

Comment: _"can be done with forEach() or a combination with reduce / map prototyping?"_ - Give it a try -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, can you provide an example or pin point a solution?

Comment: Did you read the mentioned link? Don't ask us for an opinion (_"what is the optimal way"_). Test the mentioned options, find the one that works for you and you've found the "optimal way" for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using map and forEach.

```
let newArray = array.map((x) =>{ //map to convert the first array
  let newObj = {};
  let index =0;
  keyNames.forEach((y) =>{ //forEach to loop through keynames
    newObj[y] = x[index++];  
  });
  return newObj;
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i had in mind, but i didn't knew how to advance... thank you!

Comment: Do mark this as the accepted answer, if it helped you.